# Moving from one resultset to another php

Tags: php, mysql

How to move from One Result Set to Another in PHP.

I Have created a DB Connection through mysqli method i.e mysqli('root', 'localhost', 'root', '', 'test', 3306)

**I have a Table Like one Below**

```
    CREATE TABLE Areas(AreaName VARCHAR(255),
                        PinCode VARCHAR(255))

    INSERT INTO Areas(AreaName, PinCode)
          VALUES('Teynampet', '6000018'), 
                ('Ramapuram', '6000089'),
                ('TNagar', '6000017'), 
                ('Mylapore', '6000014'), 
                ('Gopalapuram', '6000087')
```

**I have a Procedure Like one Below**

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mp_test1;
    CREATE PROCEDURE mp_test1()
    BEGIN
      SELECT AreaName FROM Areas;
      SELECT PinCode FROM Areas; 
    END
```

Now If you see the Procedure it returns two Result Sets.Please Note Result Set not Record Set.How can i Move from one Result set to another in PHP.

Dont Suggest me Inner joins for query as my requirement are not exactly the same which i posted above.My Question is moving from one resultset to another in PHP

Comment: I don't know if it is just a test but I don't see a reason for that procedure, why don't you make two separated queries?

Comment: This is not my actual requirement I have written Procedure which has queries that bring results by joining 10 tables together. If I put the same thing here I wont be in a state to explain the logic going inside neither people would be in a state to read and understand that

Comment: what is returned when you call this procedure?

Comment: some 100 to 150 records in different resultsets

Comment: what is the intention of the queries, what is the expected output you are trying to get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo) that would be the [PDOStatement::nextRowset](http://docs.php.net/pdostatement.nextrowset) method

---

When using [mysqli](http://docs.php.net/book.mysqli) the function/method to use is [mysqli::next_result](http://www.php.net/mysqli.next-result)

---

mysqli example:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly', 'test');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}


if (!$mysqli->multi_query('CALL mp_test1')) {
    echo 'error';
}
else {
    do {
        echo "--- result set ---\r\n";
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                echo join(', ', $row), "\n";
            }
            $result->free();
        }
    } while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
}
```

prints ( with the example data from the question)

```
--- result set ---
Teynampet
Ramapuram
TNagar
Mylapore
Gopalapuram
--- result set ---
6000018
6000089
6000017
6000014
6000087
--- result set ---
```

Comment: Then you might want to add to your question text which api you do use for connecting to the mysql server.

Comment: Sorry about that No i dont use any API I use only mysqli method for creating connection

Comment: mysqli::next_result doesnt works with procedure It works only for multi query